# How can I insert procedure results from server 1 into table in server 2?

Tags: sql-server, insert

The goal is to link our website to the database.  The database the website will connect to will be different then our production db.  In fact, a separate instance of SQL.  How can this be structure to execute the procedure in sql1 to populate table A in sql2 so the web query can pull from sql2 table A?

Comment: Have you thought about using a linked server ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a "linked server". This allows you to access another server tables. To do this you use the server name as a prefix.
Before addressing this option verifies with the DBAif  is an option allowed in the organization. Also check permissions issues.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) from Microsoft has more information. The following example is taken from the same link:

How to create the link?

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'SRVR002\ACCTG', 
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;
GO
```

How can reference a table from another server?

```
SELECT local.name AS LocalLogins, linked.name AS LinkedLogins
FROM master.sys.server_principals AS local
LEFT JOIN [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.server_principals AS linked
    ON local.name = linked.name ;
GO
```

Comment: I appreciate the responses and will look further into the set up of linked servers.

Comment: Glad to read it!